# DotNetNuke Custom Application Architecture

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have the task of developing a custom ASP.NET business application.  It will essentially consist of record entry and a workflow to manage these records.  We are looking to leverage a CMS and we've selected DotNetNuke at this point.  I'm wondering how we can leverage an ORM such as Entity Framework so that when we make changes to the model we only make changes in one location?

If we have highly customized forms on the front-end and want to make a change such as add a new field, how can we minimize development time for that?  Flexibility building forms is extremely important for our application.  I don't think we can use ASP.NET MVC which has the EF code-first pattern, where we would just make changes to the POCO and generate the script to changes the database and the view pages.  So I'm wondering if there's anything in DNN that offers this level of abstraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC's portion of this would not readily be possible within DOtNetNuke, however using EF Code First can be done at the data/business tier and then you handle the rest of the UI youself.

You will not have scaffolding for the UI, but in most cases scaffolding is not enough to get what people need anyway.

Comment: I guess I could follow this tutorial for doing code-first via webforms?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikreitan/archive/2012/04/10/asp-net-4-5-beta-web-forms-tutorial-series-published.aspx